# How do I add a "New" button to ALL ActiveAdmin show pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

When creating objects in ActiveAdmin I typically need to add multiple, and wish there was an option to add another object on the show page (which appears after submitting the new object).

I have been doing this model by model:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Color do

  action_item :add, only: :show do
    link_to "New", new_administration_color_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to admin/administration_color.rb

```
controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to admin_administration_color_path(resource, add_more: true) }
      end
    end
  end
```

and some modified your code

```
  action_item :add, only: :show do
    link_to "New", new_administration_color_path if params['add_more'] == true
  end
```